# Android context.getFilesDir() sometimes returns root folder

Tags: android, storage

On first time app launch I create a file using context.getFilesDir() to get the storage path. 
This works fine, except for a very small number of cases this method returns the "/" root folder. As a result the app crashes with:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /my_filename (Read-only file system)

When I debug on my device the file path is:

> /data/data/my.package/files/my_filename

This code is called in the onCreate of a SherlockActivity. So the context is that of the activity. Strangely, the failure is rare and there is no commonality among the devices where it is failing.

**Update:**
Based on the feedback so far, this code is supposed to work and the occasional failures may be due to odd devices. Trying to work around this issue is an overkill for my use case where file storage is not really mandatory. I'll try to migrate my code to use SharedPreferences.

Comment: Frankly, these sound like broken devices - perhaps faulty custom rom installs?.  That's not a call that has any documented failure modes.

Comment: Probably. Even though the failure percentage is small, in terms of absolute numbers they are worth paying attention to. I cannot stop these users from downloading and rating the app!

Comment: You could detect this and pop up something saying "defective phone detected" or use a backup location in that case.

Answer (score 4):

There is a confirmed bug in all pre-4.4 Android devices, which occurs rarely. The reason for the bug is a racing condition in creating app private directory on first launch.

The suggested fix (by Google Android team member) is to try the Context.getFilesDir() method again after first one failed with a "null" return value.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

to get the external storage directory.

use

```
Environment.getCacheDir();
```

for using the application's sandboxed cache directory.

Comment: Yes, but these return locations intended for *different purposes* than the location which the API used by the question is documented to provide.  They may or may not be viable substitutes.  And they may or may not be any more reliable than the API used in the question.

Comment: These way always worked for me without a hitch! that is why i suggested them :D

Comment: I don't see a Environment.getCacheDir() method in the documentation. I'm just storing some settings. I don't want to get in the way of the user's other files.

Comment: You need to use sharedpreferences in order to store settings. It is the proper way to do so! Please refer to the android documentation regarding sharedpreferences.

Comment: Correction - you *might consider* using shared preferences.  But there's nothing wrong with what the question is trying to do - it is supposed to work, and would if the device is compliant with the Android APIs.

Comment: I am using both SharedPreferences and file storage (because of some open source code I copied). If I understand why this failure is happening I'll try to fix it. Otherwise I'll probably migrate my code to use settings.